# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/yaml

Tags: maven, apache-storm

I'm new in using storm trying to submit storm-starter but when i

```
mvn package
```

i got that error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/yaml/snakeyaml/constructor/BaseConstructor, 
compiling:(word_count.clj:16:1)
at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.eval(Compiler.java:3463)
```

[POM file here in the link](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/examples/storm-starter/pom.xml)

Comment: Did you follow the readme instructions? https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/examples/storm-starter

Comment: can you help on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33851674/upgrade-version-of-storm

Answer (score 6):

A common problem when getting a ClassPath error like the one you got, is that you might have a collision from transitive dependencies; i.e., there's at least two artifacts that are providing different versions of the Class Not Found, you need to exclude the colliding one. So you have to identify the collision, e.g. in maven do:

    `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`

and look for the colliding artifact, in your case the uri:

    `org/yaml/snakeyaml/constructor/BaseConstructor`

identifies maven coordinates, groupId=org.yaml, and artifactId=snakeyaml
, you'll find that the artifact "testing" in your case was providing another snakeyaml and thus add an exclusion as you did to that artifact's dependency:
```

```
<exclusions>
  <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

```

Answer (score 2):

```
<!-- just expanding/clarifying on the previous answer: -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```