# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/yaml/snakeyaml/constructor/BaseConstructor

Tags: java, android, flutter, yaml

When I am trying to run flutter app in simulator i get error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/yaml/snakeyaml/constructor/BaseConstructor
    at org.testng.internal.YamlParser.parse(YamlParser.java:16)
    at org.testng.internal.YamlParser.parse(YamlParser.java:10)
    at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:168)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:311)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:46)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 more

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the JAR file for snakeyaml from the classpath.  However, judging from the stacktrace, you are not running a flutter app at this point.  It *looks* like that the exception is occurring in the testng launcher.

So I suspect that the problem is a version conflict between the versions of snakeyaml required by the test framework and something you are testing.  Here is an example Q&A from a different context:

- [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33793441/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-yaml)

The work-around in that case was to exclude nestng's transitive snakeyaml dependency; see above link for the details.  (You will most likely need to map from the Maven POM syntax to the equivalent Gradle syntax.)